# how to set controller by keyboard arrows in matlab app designer

Tags: matlab

I have a problem to set controller by keyboard arrows in matlab app designer.
I cant reset my key value when there is no key Pressed.
I want to make action only while some key is pressing and stop the action when the key is un pressing

```
  function ControllerUIFigureKeyPress(app, event)
        key = event.Key;
        switch key
            case 'leftarrow'
                app.left_icon.Position = [210 98 71 102];
            case 'uparrow'
                app.up_icon.Position = [285 150 71 102];
            case 'rightarrow'
                 app.right_icon.Position = [360 98 71 102];
            case 'downarrow'
                 app.down_icon.Position = [285 40 71 102];
            otherwise
                app.down_icon.Position = [285 60 71 102];
                app.up_icon.Position = [285 133 71 102];
                app.right_icon.Position = [343 98 71 102];
                app.left_icon.Position = [225 98 71 102];
        end
```